# How do I match a month range in the database to two dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Assume I have a table that contains a `from_month` (int, 1-12) and a `to_month` (int, 1-12) column, and I then have another table that contains a `from` (int, unix timestamp) and `to` (int, unix timestamp) column.

How would I match rows where the `from_month` and `to_month` columns contain my `from` and `to` timestamps, taking into account year boundaries on either side?

Scenario:

- With `from_month` as *11* and `to_month` as *2*, is there a way where I can get a `from` value of *1383264000* and a `to` value of *1391212800* to match?

At the same time however:

- With `from_month` as *3* and `to_month` *8*, is there a way where I can get a `from` value of *1362096000* and a `to` value of *1375315200* to match?

Clarifications:

- I need records from the second table where the months from both timestamps fall between the range set out from the first table.
- Also, I can obtain the month from the timestamp, so it's not necessary for MySQL to parse it, but the solution is likely unaffected.

Comment: You really shouldn't be working with unix timestamps in MySQL.  Use date, datetime, timestamp fields and this problem becomes trivial.

Comment: Show some table entries and expected output in table format

Comment: What year do you take if you have only month fields in first table?

Comment: Unix timestamp shows the number of seconds that have passed since January 1st, 1970. You can use it to calculate the month on the second table.

Comment: I'm trying to match based on contiguous ranges of months.  The range will only be within a year or across two years.  Never more.

Comment: Re: Unix timestamps in MySQL, I agree 100%.  Unfortunately that is outside of my control for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i'm not sure how you want to compare with the `year`

But if only month, you can use [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to get date from a unixtime, and [`MONTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) to get month from a date

for example

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1391212800)
> February, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000

SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1391212800))
> 2
```

with the month get from unix time, I'm sure you can do the rest or help explain more detail what you want to.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL how to create unix timestamp from your input :

```
SELECT 
    @year:= YEAR(CURDATE()),
    @from:= CONCAT(@year, '-', 11, '-1') AS from_date,
    @to:= CONCAT(IF(11<=2, @year, @year+1), '-', 2, '-1') AS to_date,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@from) AS from_timestamp,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@to) AS to_timestamp;
```

Month 11 & 2 are hard-coded. I used variables, so the sql is shorter.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ca56/1)

---

Your scenario is :

> With from_month as 11 and to_month as 2, is there a way where I can get a from value of 1383264000 and a to value of 1391212800 to match?

Which is from `2013-11-01 00:00:00` to `2014-02-01 00:00:00`. Are you sure you need `TO date` to be from first of the month? or the last day of the Februar?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as we're only matching the months.  Year, day, time don't matter.  Just that what we're matching shows up in the contiguous range created by `from_month` and `to_month`

Comment: @Omega: so you need records from second table where `WHERE from = '1383264000' AND to = '1391212800'` ?

Comment: I need records from the second table where the months from both timestamps fall between the range set out from the first table.

Comment: @Omega: can you give me the example how should the end sql look like? Is it: `SELECT * FROM second WHERE from >= '1383264000' AND '1391212800' <= to` ?

Comment: Yeah, WHERE from >= 3 AND to <= 8.  You don't have to worry about parsing the month from the timestamp if that helps.  The real trick is getting the same check to work when from is the larger value.

Comment: Ok, so from my answer you now know how to convert `3` to timestamp?

Comment: I think that could get into a lot of checks with different scenarios if I tried to "simulate" a date with my month values...

Answer (score 0):

A solution was found that does an inclusive month check using months as integers from *0-11*.

```
# Filter
SET @Fs = 2; # Mar
SET @Fe = 7; # Aug
# 
SET @Ps = 2; # Mar
SET @Pe = 4; # May

SELECT

    (
        (
            MOD(@Pe - @Fs + 24, 12) <= MOD(@Fe - @Fs + 24, 12)
        ) 
        AND (
            MOD(@Ps - @Fs + 24, 12) <= MOD(@Pe - @Fs + 24, 12)
        )
    ) 
    OR MOD(@Fe - @Fs + 24, 12)=11;
```